# HQL where clause with HashSet in hibernate(Iam using hbm,xml for mapping)

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have two tables `Item_category` and `site_items`. There is a one-to-many relation with `Item_category` to `site_items`. and the POJO class of `Item_category` contains

```
Set<SiteItems> items = new HashSet<SiteItems>();
```

My real problem is when I query the two tables I want to put a condition with `Set<SiteItems>` in the where clause.
ie; I want to get the `item_category` info from `site_items` with matching the pkey and `SiteItems.siteItemLevel='CAT'`.

My current query is

```
from ItemCategory where items.itemLevel='CAT'
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Answer (score 0):

Since POJO class of Item_category contains

```
Set<SiteItems> items = new HashSet<SiteItems>();
```

So The query should be

```
from ItemCategory where ItemCategory.items.itemLevel='CAT'
```